# what this code under RijndaelManaged means?

Tags: c#

I just want to know what this codes means? I have tried to put it in C# compiler but it does not work.

```
    private byte[] Method_05(string A_0, string A_1)
{
    RijndaelManaged managed = new RijndaelManaged {
        Key = Convert.FromBase64String(A_0),
        IV = Convert.FromBase64String(A_1)
    };strong text
    Stream manifestResourceStream = base.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("s.Assembly");
    CryptoStream stream2 = new CryptoStream(manifestResourceStream, managed.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[manifestResourceStream.Length];
    stream2.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    stream2.Close();
    manifestResourceStream.Close();
    return buffer;
}
```

exactly here :

```
Stream manifestResourceStream = base.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("s.Assembly");
CryptoStream stream2 = new CryptoStream(manifestResourceStream, managed.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
byte[] buffer = new byte[manifestResourceStream.Length];
stream2.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
stream2.Close();
manifestResourceStream.Close();
return buffer;
```

Comment: Which bit *precisely* is confusing you? What do you mean by "it does not work" exactly? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

You mean `Stream manifestResourceStream = base.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("s.Assembly");`?

It reads a resource of the assembly the parent class of this class is in(`base` references the parent class. Parent class and child class don't necessarily have to be in the same assembly). After reading that, it gets decrypted using the Rijndael algorithm.

Considering the other parts and naming of the method, you are looking at the dynamic loading of piece of code in an obfuscated assembly (However, this is purely guesswork).

Answer (score 2):

This one retrieves the stream from resources embedded into the assembly where the base class of the one containing the method is defined. It's impossible to determine what kind of stream is that, it can be anything, a text file, an image.

Then it decompresses it using the RinjdaelManaged compression algorithm.

Comment: what about this line?

byte[] buffer = new byte[manifestResourceStream.Length];